# css scroll bar of a div within a dynamic container

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a screen divided into 3 columns spanning the full height of the screen, I would like to have a scroll bar within each of the 3 sections, not one for the entire page. Everything I find suggested is with a fixed height of the container element. Is it possible to have this setup with a fluid dynamic height?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set to the 3 elements have the height of the screen, so it doesn't block the page scroll, and they fills the entire screen

```
.column {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible not to have page wide scroll bar at all? just the per-section ones? each clipping to the bottom of the screen height

Comment: Yes, you just add `overflow: hidden` to the `body` tag

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the elements to the height of the screen and overflow to auto using css:

```
height: 100vh;
overflow:auto;
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h7qkcnw1/

hope that helps.